# How to open already opened activity instead of creating new one?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities with "navigation menu" which has items for launching Activity1 and Activity2.
For example we starts Activity2 from Activity1 and then we want open Activity1 by tap on "navigation menu", but when we do this we get new instance of Activity1 instead of open еxisting instance.
How can i open instance of Activity1 if it already exists and create new instance if not?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to your `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`.

Comment: But using this, oncreate() method is not called? what to do if I want to  refresh the activity with new data passed to it? Onresume() is there, But is there is any other way to do the same?

Comment: @JD.com: Either `onCreate()` or `onNewIntent()` should be called in either case.

Comment: Some example code for future readers: `Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);` then `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`. As well, `intent.addFlags(...)` works, but it depends on your **intent**ions :P

Answer (score 6):

add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to your activity in the `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) out about different launchModes
also mind this:

> As shown in the table above, standard is the default mode and is
>   appropriate for most types of activities. SingleTop is also a common
>   and useful launch mode for many types of activities. The other modes —
>   singleTask and singleInstance — are not appropriate for most
>   applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely
>   to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other
>   applications

Answer (score 5):

The most complete answer would be to use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and depending on your functionality, override [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) since it will be called if there is already an instance of the `Activity` with the new Intent passed to it.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Why?

Based on the question.
There are two Activities, **Activity1** & **Activity2**

We open **Activity1** and then from **Activity1** we open **Activity2**. Then, inside **Activity2**:

> How can i open instance of **Activity1** if it already exists and create new instance if not?

As stated in [AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode) for `singleTask`

> If, when starting the activity, there is already a task running that starts with this activity, then instead of starting a new instance the current task is brought to the front. The existing instance will receive a call to Activity.onNewIntent() with the...

Furthermore, under the intent class, if you read about the `singleTask launchMode` it already uses `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` and manually setting an intent to it is not normally set by application code.

As stated in [FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)

> int FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT
>   This flag is not normally set by application code, but set for you by the system as described in the launchMode documentation for the singleTask mode.

Therefore, by using `singleTask launchMode` you ensure that there is only one instance of your application and you do not have to be adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` flag to your intents in every activity which calls your **Activity2** as suggested by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293820/how-to-open-already-opened-activity-instead-of-creating-new-one/7293935#7293935).

Now, if we use the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` as [weakwire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293820/how-to-open-already-opened-activity-instead-of-creating-new-one/7293893#7293893) suggested, the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) he provided himself clearly states;

> "singleTop"...In other circumstances — for example, if an existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

In other words, we would end up with multiple instances of **Activity1** in some scenarios which is what we do not want.

As final say, if you are one of those who love editing answers that contribute nothing to the answer itself, go answer some real questions if you really want to increase your Stack Overflow Reputation.

Comment: I think this is the best answer with more complete explanation that makes me understand easier...

Answer (score 3):

Set the flag of the activity to `singleTask` and override the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` to catch the new intent.