# Unable to open existing which is running activity when click on local notification

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, background, localnotification

I am implementing local notification for my app.
problem: when I click on the notification it open the app from the start. But I want to open the application from the same screen where the application entered in the background.

Solution that I already tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, new Random().nextInt(), intent, 0);
```

I tried many flag setting but none of them are working
and `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` also not working.

I've tried from this link also [How to open already opened activity instead of creating new one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7293820/10217433) but that's not working for me.

PLATFORM: Android 9 (pie),
Minimum API: 24.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just resume your app without starting specific activity, just don't specify `PendingIntent`. In that case, when app will be closed, Android will start your app from the beginning on user click. But, if your app is still running, it will be resumed.
For example, you can use the following

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");


    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service//

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =

        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: No its not working if you can't setContentIntent() it's just a notification which is non-clickable

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by many ways.

By experience, the easiest solution for this problem is finishing the starting activity before it is displayed. If your starting activity only appears when the app is starting you can do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```

If it is not your case, you can create an Intent for a "phantom activity". The phantom activity may close if the app is running or it may redirect to the starting activity if the app is not running.

Comment: I can't do this coz I need to pass some parameters which is not good….

Answer (score 0):

Another more complex way is to use deep links, it is specially recommended if you will navigate through the app after the user clicked on the notification:

- Nice medium article to start on deep links: https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd
- Android documentation about deep links: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

You can also pass information through the app using Broadcasts:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts
- https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be